# Sequence combinations of varying length using two 'alphabets'

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, permutation, combinations, bioinformatics

I am trying to generate all possible combinations of a sequence of length k given a certain alphabet (this is to generate query sequences for a bioinformatics project).

The sequences are of the form:

A first character and last character that can be any of A C G U (call these Y) and k - 2 characters in between that can be any of A C G U or ? (call these X).

e.g. if k = 3 then the pattern is of the form YXY and if k = 5 then YXXXY.

Generating all possible sequences if k is known is easy, as you can just use k nested for loops. But if k is not known in advance, then this implementation does not fit.

The total number of possible sequences can be expressed by 4^2 * 5^(k-2). With k = 3 this only gives 80 combinations, but scale that up to k = 9 and you have 1,250,000!

Any tips, ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

I need to use every sequence generated, so they need to be either stored in an array, or passed at creation/generation to another function, it doesn't really matter which, although I would prefer not to have to store all of them.

Many Thanks.

N.B. I am writing in objective-c, but any c-style code, or psuedocode or just plain english descriptions of an algorithm would be helpful.

UPDATE:

Here is the objc code I wrote base on the brilliant answer by Analog File. Currently it just outputs one sequence per line to stdout, but I will modify it to produce an array of strings.

Many thanks to everyone who contributed.

```
    NSArray *yAlphabet = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"C", @"G", @"U", nil];
    NSArray *xAlphabet = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"C", @"G", @"U", @"?", nil];
    int i, v;
    int count = 0;
    int numberOfCases = 16 * pow(5 , (k - 2));
    for (int n = 0; n < (numberOfCases); n++) {
        i = n;
        v = i % 4;
        i = i / 4;
        count++;
        printf("\n%s", [[yAlphabet objectAtIndex:v] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        for (int m = 1; m < (k - 1); m++) {
            v = i % 5;
            i = i / 5;
            printf("%s", [[xAlphabet objectAtIndex:v] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        }
        printf("%s", [[yAlphabet objectAtIndex:i] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    NSLog(@"No. Sequences: %i", count);
```

UPDATE 2:

And here's the code, outputting the generated sequences to an array of strings. Note that k is the length of the desired sequences and is given as a parameter elsewhere. I have tested this up to k=9 (1,250,000 sequences). Also note that my code uses ARC, hence there is no memory deallocation shown.

```
    NSArray *yAlphabet = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"C", @"G", @"U", nil];
    NSArray *xAlphabet = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"C", @"G", @"U", @"?", nil];
    NSMutableArray *sequences = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int i, v;
    int count = 0;
    int numberOfCases = 16 * pow(5 , (k - 2));
    for (int n = 0; n < (numberOfCases); n++) {
        i = n;
        v = i % 4;
        i = i / 4;
        count++;
        NSMutableString *seq = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[yAlphabet objectAtIndex:v]];
        for (int m = 1; m < (k - 1); m++) {
            v = i % 5;
            i = i / 5;
            [seq appendString:[xAlphabet objectAtIndex:v]];
        }
        [seq appendString:[yAlphabet objectAtIndex:i]];
        [sequences addObject:seq];
    }
    NSLog(@"No. Sequences looped: %i", count);

    //print the array to confirm
    int count1 = 0;
    for (NSMutableString *str in sequences) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        count1++;
    }
    NSLog(@"No. Sequences printed: %i", count1);
    NSLog(@"Counts match? : %@", (count == count1 ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
```

Comment: added tags algorithm and permutations, I did not remove combinations because, even if incorrect, many would still use that in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how many cases you are going to get. 
This is pseudocode (k is the sequence length)

```
 for n = 0 to num_of_cases - 1

    i = n

    v = i % length_of_alphabeth_Y
    i = i / length_of_alphabeth_Y
    output vth char in alphabeth Y

    for m = 1 to k-1
       v = i % length_of_alphabeth_X
       i = i / length_of_alphabeth_X
       output vth char in alphabeth X

    output ith char in alphabeth Y
    output end of sequence
```

Each iteration of the outer loop generates a case.I wrote `output` but it's easy to instead "store" the data in a dynamically allocated structure (n indexes in the roes, first case is column 0 then m indexes in the columns and last case is column k-1. if you do that "end of sequence" need not be output as it's subsumed by the increment of n).

Note how we are effectively "counting" in base length_of_alphabeth, except we use different bases depending on the digit. Modulo gives you the least significant digit, and integer division gets rid of it and shifts next digit to least significant position.

If you can imagine n as being just a *value*, in no specific base, the logic is rather simple. You could probably write this yourself from scratch, once you understand it.

Comment: These aren't really combinations or permutations, they're more like generating numbers with a combination of bases.

Comment: Ok, this should now be correct. Stupid me I did not re-read and did mistakes, needed to re edit trice in few seconds, lol

Comment: It's 4 AM here, calling it a night. If you do not manage to make that into ObjC, I could give it a try tomorrow (aka, a bit later today, lol).

Comment: Perhaps it would be correct to say that I am looking for every possible permutation of every possible combination of length k?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see the updates, thanks for all of your work! I'll keep working on it (different timezones!) and post anything I come up with.

Comment: @beanstalker - No, this terminology doesn't work.  "every possible combination of length k" - combinations require an 'n' as in n choose k. k choose k is 1.  Permutations are like shuffling.

Comment: @AnalogFile Brilliant! Works a treat, thank you! Have edited the question with the working code.

Answer (score 0):

The basic form for doing this looks like this (Java-ish psuedocode)

```
char[] output = new char[k];
pubilc void go(cur_k){
   if(cur_k>k) // do something - copy the array and store it, etc.
   for( char letter : alphabet ){
       output[cur_k]=char_letter;
       go(cur_k+1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like k will be passed in as a parameter, so something like this (in Python-ish pseudo-code) should work

```
Y_alphabet = ['A','C','G','U']
X_alphabet = ['A','C','G','U','?']

outputs = []

for i in range(k):
    if i == 0 or i == k-1:
        current_alphabet = Y_alphabet
    else:
        current_alphabet = X_alphabet

    last_outputs = outputs
    outputs = []

    for next_character in current_alphabet:
        # This just replaces outputs with a new list that consists
        # of all the possible sequences of length i appended with
        # the current character
        outputs += [seq + next_character for seq in last_outputs]
```