# All possible combinations of words with given set of words

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, string

I have a given set of alphabets say 11 letters. I want to find all possible word combinations of specific length say 5. These are numbers are dynamic. It doesn't matter to me if the resulted words do have a meaning or not.

Can someone please provide me with this kind of code or algo to follow. Or guide me right direction.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "if they have meaning or not". Do you just want to know every possible combination? Or do you mean actual words? What language?

Comment: i mean if the combination generated is a english word or not it doesn't metter.. I would prefer the code in objective c language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this SO Question:

[Sequence combinations of varying length using two 'alphabets'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944311/sequence-combinations-of-varying-length-using-two-alphabets)

Read "UPDATE 2:" in this question there he post his working code

All the best

Answer (score 2):

This algorithm is a [permutation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). A relatively easy way is to use recursion to solve it.

Comment: can i get some code for this to do this task

Comment: @Tornado On SO, we don't write your homework for you. Show what code you have tried so far and what was the problem with it, and we'll try to figure out how to fix it.